# Python3 catch all list indices to get access of dicts

Tags: python-3.x

i've the following input:

```
mylist = [{street:long, name:foo, color:blue},{street=short,name:bar,color:red},{street:mid, name:me, color:black})
```

when i try:

```
mylist[*][name]
list indices must be integers, not str
```

so, how can i get all 'names' of this list with sub-dicts?

Comment: Please do not leave out quotes when posting code, they are there for a reason.

Comment: What is this `List[*]` syntax?  I don't recognize it, and neither does my python3 installation..

Answer (score 0):

I don't recognize the star subscript syntax; perhaps you are thinking of a different language?

The usual Pythonic way would be a list comprehension:

```
mylist = [
  {'street':'long', 'name':'foo', 'color':'blue'},
  {'street':'short','name':'bar','color':'red'},
  {'street':'mid', 'name':'me', 'color':'black'}
]
[entry['name'] for entry in mylist]
# => ['foo', 'bar', 'me']
```

Although you could also use a `map`:

```
map(lambda e: e['name'], mylist)
#=> ['foo', 'bar', 'me']
```